# Unable to update a single column value in table

Tags: mysql

I am new to store procedure. I have customer table and it has column like customerid, customerName,companyName. I am creating new column email_address. Which is working fine. now I am trying to add email address values for each customer using store procedure. and I am taking customername and companyName in email address. but somehow it is not updating. here is my code after variable declaration

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test() 
BEGIN
DECLARE variable
DECLARE  CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, EmailAddress
FROM customers;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER 

 OPEN cursor_name;

WHILE row_not_found = FALSE 
    DO      
            FETCH customers_cursor 
            INTO customer_id_var, company_name_var, contact_name_var, email_id_var;

            SET email_part1 = REPLACE (contact_name_var, ' ', '' );
            SET email_part2 = substring_index(company_name_var, ' ', 1);    

            update customers 
            SET EmailAddress = CONCAT(email_part1, '@', email_part2, '.com')
            WHERE CustomerID = customer_id_var;

            SET update_count = update_count + 1;


    END WHILE;

CLOSE cursor_name;    

  SELECT * FROM customers;

END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL test();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cursor for this:

```
update customers
    set EmailAddress = CONCAT(REPLACE(contact_name_var, ' ', '' ), '@',
                              substring_index(company_name_var, ' ', 1), '.com');
```

This is much simpler than using a cursor and it should perform better.

(I am not going to comment on the actual logic for creating the email address, other than to say that it seems likely to fail under many circumstances.)